# How can I view how many agreements I completed on Adobe Sign?

Tags: adobe-sign

I tried to search for "completed" in the [completed agreement list](https://adobe.na1.adobesign.com/public/agreements/?dc_remove=true#agreement_type=agreement&agreement_state=completed), but due to how the list is shown, that doesn't work:

[image]

I tried to click on the checkbox that check all completed agreements, but it refuses to select over 100 agreements:

[image]

I also unsuccessfully tried to look at the source:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I knew nothing about [Adobe Sign](https://www.adobe.com/sign.html) when I *created* this answer, but I learned a bit about how [web applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application) work. I have been working as a [freelancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freelancer) for several years, helping people to resolve situations like this. I'm sharing a few of my "secrets" in this answer.

The first thing to remember is that web applications might not be "hackable" (in the good sense; see the Update section at the bottom of this answer) as they used to be 10 or 20 years ago. Suppose the data you seek is unavailable on the [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) using the web browser developer tools. In that case, an *affordable* thing that you might do is to look at the app documentation to see if there is a "store" of extensions, plug-ins, add-ons pointed to end-users, and an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API).

If there is an *API*, it might be possible for "any programmer" with the proper authorizations to retrieve the data you seek. Anyone who can write computer commands, aka code, is a programmer. Nowadays, several web IDEs like Google Apps Script and GitHub Codespaces can be used on web browsers to access the data you are looking for, so it might not take too much effort to get you ready to use the *Adobe Sign API*, it exists. It's worth noting that Google Apps Script has the Fetch service that saves a lot of the hassle of setting up a computer to use *APIs*.

Usually, the web app documentation for end-users and programmers is available at the "person on keyboard" fingertips; Adobe Sign might have a **Help** menu or even an AI chatbot. Large companies like Google and Adobe had plenty of resources for end-users.

Start looking at the Adobe Sign user interface. UI elements should be clearly labeled so the end-user will understand that they will be pointed to the documentation, open a tool, a walk-through guide, etc.

If you have problems finding the required solution, try looking at the Adobe website. It should have a search engine.

The "last" but most of the time used as the first resource is using the web browser "omnibox". Type a query and press enter; it should open a web page showing the results of a default web search engine, typically Google.

Be careful when using an AI chatbot as they can "hallucinate" and make you waste time if you are not familiar with the knowledge domain that you will chat about with the bot, in this case, about Adobe Sing and how web applications work.

The more that you know about Adobe Sign and the extensibility and programming terms that you know the better chances to find a easy to follow instructions to get what you are looking for.

## Update

Below, I will be adding what I am learning about **Adobe Sign** and how to know how many contracts have been signed by an Adobe Sign end-user.

As of February 14, 2024 the following is the top of the Adobe website for the United States (*Your mileage might vary*):

[image: Snapshot of the top of the Adobe website for the United States]

This website is responsive, so on narrow screens, instead of the toolbar shown on the top, it shows a **Menu** button.

## Related

### About *hackable* (in the good sense)

The word **hack** and its derivations have several uses. In this context, I think that the following definition of **hacker** might work as a starting point:

From https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hacker (only included plain text)

> 6. (computing, dated) One who is expert at programming and solving problems with a computer. quotations ▼
>    (by extension) One who applies a novel method, shortcut, skill, or trick to something to increase ease, efficiency, or productivity.
>    food hacker    growth hacker

A related Wikipedia articles: [Hacker Culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_culture).

### About documentation at the fingertips of the "person on keyboard"

It has become an "industry standard" for application software developers to include a user interface element pointing to the documentation and resources for end-users. A common label is **Help**. Some apps instead of might have a button with a question mark, or other "creative" ways to point end-users to the resources for them.

Related Wikipedia article: [Online Help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_help)

### Another option, use a third-party no-code / low-code "app"

As mentioned in the top section of this answer, web apps are no longer what they were to be long ago. With the emergence of Web 2.0, besides empowering end-users to post content to **The Web**, many companies turned their web apps into *digital services* and APIs evolved over the years. Nowadays, most "web apps" from large companies like Adobe are not stand-alone products. They are part of a **platform** including products for programmers. Web apps with a large user base usually offer APIs that almost anyone can use. Some are required to register as developers. Some might require a fee, while others allow developers to register for free.

#### No-code / Low code services

One of the novelties that "The Web 2.0" brings to the market is web apps that automate other web apps. I think that two of the first to become notable were [IFTTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFTTT) and [Zapier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zapier). Nowadays, there are tons of these kinds of "apps". Some offer ready-to-use automation for the most popular web apps and most common end-user tasks for free.